# Running electron (atom-shell) headlessly on linux server through Nightmare.js

Tags: node.js, xvfb, headless-browser, electron, nightmare

I am building a scraper to make JS single page applications easily crawlable.

After some incredible **frustration with PhantomJS** (memory leaks, outdated webkit, undead processes, among many other problems) I decided to switch to [NightmareJS](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) which can do the same things but uses [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) under the hood. Electron has a lot of advantages (uses **latest chromium**, is a lot faster) but it needs an X server to run.

As I need to make it work under ubuntu server, I followed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/AspireToCodeBetter/130877925f52c8fb2557) . Now I have a great EC2 instance with everything ready to run an **headless electron**

```
xvfb-run electron
```

The point is that I need to run this through nightmareJS (which I will use in a node.js server script). I was wondering how I could **pass parameters to nightmare in order to start electron through svfb**

Comment: You probably should ask this in the [Nightmare issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues). The move to electron is pretty new and I don't know if the developers frequent Stack Overflow.

Comment: The link to the gist is broken. I need this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way, but at least for my works run the main process using xvfb-run command:

```
$ xvfb-run node --harmony simple-service.js
Worker 12153 is online
Worker 12155 is online
Worker 12154 is online
Worker 12156 is online
```

Comment: Will multiple instances of Nightmare work when running it like this?